# what is rpm fusion in layman and how it is related to installing vlc?

Tags: linux, fedora, vlc-media-player, rpm

Recently i installed *VLC Player* on fedora. Since i am a new user for linux i installed it without knowing what am i doing. I just followed the instructions. First i installed         [a rpm file for fedora 16 from this link](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration),then configured it as given on the same page,then installed it using `yum install vlc`. It took a minute or two and the player was installed.

Now what is *RPM Fusion* in layman ?

How is downloading *vlc player* related to rpm fusion ?

Can anyone please explain how did the installation happen ? !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Answer:

RPM Fusion is a software repository for RPM-based Linux distributions.

For some reason unknown to me, Fedora won't include VLC in their official repos (repositories) (licencing issue?), and VideoLAN won't set up their own (laziness?); so they direct people to RPM Fusion.

Comment: what does configuring _( as given [here:http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration))_ the rpm file mean ? Only after configuring it i can enter the yum command

Comment: Fedora does not come pre-configured to access RPM Fusion's repositories, only the official update repos. By "configuring", they mean that you'll have to configure YUM to access these 3rd party repos. RPM Fusion provides a set of RPMs which configure YUM automatically.

Comment: @PhantmKllr some of the codecs have patent issues, specifically MP3. So, the base repos don't have any code with licensing issues, but you can add repos if you like. VideoLan doesn't want to code for every distro, so they drop the source, let you compile it.